# Why is char *str = "anything" always the size of 8?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, byte

I was testing around with `sprintf` a bit to convert an `int` into a `string`/`char` and noticed something:

1. When I make a `string` like this

`char *str = "anything";`

no matter what I write in it, `sizeof` always returns a value of 8 byte.
But as far as I know, a `char` is ususally the size of 1 byte, so why doesn't the number of characters in the string/array change its size?

If I write

`char str[15];`

I get a size of 15 bytes, so why do I not get a size of 15 bytes if I type

```
char *str = "11111111111111\0"
```

but a size of 8 bytes?

2. Similar to this, if I type

`char str[] = {"67"}`

`sizeof` returns a value of 3 byte, which makes sense since it is 6, 7 and \0.
And then I write this

```
int aInt = 368;
sprintf(str, "%d", aInt);
```

to convert `int aInt 368` into a string and write that string into `str`.
These are three `char` then, and therefor, `sizeof` should return a value of 4 byte, counting \0 in.
But it still returns 1, even through I wrote 3 chars.

Can anyone explain this to me, please?

This is the piece of code with which I've been testing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *arfv[])
{

    int aInt = 368;

    printf("value of aInt: %d\n", aInt);

    char str[15];
    //Other ways of creating a string/array which were tested:
    //char *str = "anything";
    //char str[] = {"67"};

    //printf("value of str before: %s\n", str); //value of str before converting

    printf("size of str before: %ld\n", sizeof(str)); //size of str before converting

    sprintf(str, "%d", aInt); //convert aInt into a string

    printf("value of str after: %s\n", str); //value of str after converting

    printf("size of str after: %ld\n", sizeof(str)); //size of str after converting

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pointer is not an array, and `sizeof` can't read your mind.

Comment: You're running on a 64-bit processor, so memory addresses (and therefore the size of pointer objects) are 64 bits.

Comment: Why is this question being down-voted? The OP has asked a reasonable question and has supplied a short example illustrating the behaviour he/she is confused about.

Comment: "a `char` is ususally the size of 1 byte" -> a `char` has size exactly 1, no exceptions. `char` is the *unit of measurement* for `sizeof`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `char*` is just a pointer to some memory, and has a size of whatever a pointer is on your architecture (8 bytes would indicate a 64-bit architecture, 4 bytes would indicate 32-bit).

Since pointers convey no information about the size of the allocation they point to, `sizeof` will not evaluate to the size of the allocation, it will simply tell you how large the *pointer* is.  Further, note that `sizeof` is a *compile time* construct; its value is evaluated fully at compile time.

```
char *ptr = "1234567890";
char str[10] = "12345";
int numbers[10];
```

- `sizeof(ptr)` evaluates the size of the pointer. The value will typically be 4 (32-bit) or 8 (64-bit).
- `sizeof(*ptr)` evaluates the size of `char`. (1)
- `sizeof(str)` evaluates the size of the array. (Its size is 10 bytes, even though only 6 were assigned.)
- `sizeof(numbers)` will evaluate to `sizeof(int) * 10`.

Comment: Unless applied to a VLA. Also, it's an operator so the parentheses are superfluous whe not applied to a type.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification. The book I am learning with only stated that there are two syntaxes for creating a string, and didn't say that one of them was a pointer. Never heard of them, I'll take a look at that topic.

Comment: About the second part of my question: So sizeof doesn't change its returning value when I increase the size of an array, but keeps the number of chars the array had at its creation? Because, when I have `char str[] = {"67"};` and I delete the sizeof before the int is converted, and only check afterwards, it still returns a value of 3.

Comment: @Merlin You cannot change the size of an array. Can you paste some code where you *think* you are resizing it, so I can explain what you are actually doing?

Comment: @Deduplicator Parens are superfluous anywhere they are not required by the syntax. So is whitespace. That doesn't mean we don't use them for readability.

Comment: Sure. But I would argue the additional parens are not helping readability there. Anyway, let's not start a style-war.

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't start anything. ;)

Comment: @cdhowie `int aInt = 3638;
char str[] = {"67"};
sprintf(str, "%d", aInt);` I have a string with no specified length. Then, I give that string 3 chars: 6, 7 and \0 . And then, I convert an integer made of 4 digits into a string, which would therefor be made of 5 chars, 3, 6, 3, 8 and \0 and write that string into str. Thus, making str grow from 3 to 5 chars.

Comment: @cdhowie But, I think I am wrong at the part of the string made from the integer being 5 chars long, because when I specify the length of str to 3, it shouldn't be able to hold all 5 chars written to it, but when I run it like that, I in fact get the whole number printed out. (Actually, I used `sizeof` in the first place to find out how the sizes of the variables change due to converting, but that didn't work out exactly well...)

Comment: @Merlin `char str[] = {"67"};` does not create an array of "no specified length," it creates an array of 3 elements. When you convert an integer of 4 digits into the array you overrun the bounds of the array. This causes *undefined behavior* (UB). In this case you are simply writing beyond the end of the array into whatever variables happen to come after the array on the stack; in other words, you are just corrupting your program's state. "Works like the programmer intended" is one possible outcome of UB, but a crash or data corruption is also possible. *Anything at all* might happen. Avoid UB

Comment: @Merlin Note that you *cannot* reason about UB. UB is one of the worst things you can cause because you *can't know* what will happen. It's like playing Russian roulette, but where on each trigger pull the gun might kill you, it might not, it might kill your friend, it might kill your neighbor, it might give your dog fleas, it might turn into a vase filled with flowers.

Comment: @cdhowie So, by converting an int into a string which is shorter than the int(causing UB), I write unclean code. Thank you, I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @Merlin Consider using `snprintf()` instead, which lets you specify the maximum number of characters to write. This will prevent UB by having the function stop before it overruns the array. `if (snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", aInt) == sizeof(str)) { /* the string was too small */ }` Note that if `snprintf()` stops early then a **null terminating character has not been written** and trying to write the string without first replacing the last character with a null terminator will also cause UB.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` gives you the number of bytes necessary to store a value of a given type. For a `char *` this is usually 4 or 8 bytes. A `char *` can store a memory address were you may find `char`s. How many `char`s are at such an address ? If these `char`s encode a C-string, then you can use `strlen` to get the length of the string.